# BibTeX proceedings with acmart

Tags: bibliographies, acm, acmart

I'm using the acmart class and proceedings items in my bibliography look rather odd, e.g.,

```
[1] IEEE 1997. Proc. 12th Symposium on Logic in Computer Science. IEEE.
```

I've tried a few variations, without success.

What I'd like is something like:

```
[X] IEEE. Proc. 12th Symposium on Logic in Computer Science, 1997.
```

(for X, I don't really care, but I guess it should be sorted as if IEEE
was the author).

Here is a MEWB:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\citestyle{acmnumeric}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@proceedings{DBLP:conf/lics/1997,
  author = {},
  key = {LICS 1997},
  organization = {IEEE},
  year      = {1997},
  title     = {Proc.\ 12th Symposium on Logic in Computer Science},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{DBLP:conf/lics/1997}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Any hints please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to your question. We need it not only to reproduce your problem but also to test our suggestions. So it would help us to help you. BTW: Do you want this change only for proceedings?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks, just edited. And yes, only proceedings appear to be problematic, as far as I can see.

Comment: The format of the references is “author. year. Full text.”; the only oddity I see is that there is no period in the case of `@proceedings` after the editor/organization.

Comment: @egreg And `organization` is used twice. At the beginning (instead of empty author) and at the end.

Comment: @Schweinebacke That seems a precise choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: If you want to publish an article at ACM, you should not do any change on the style but use it as it is or you should at least ask the editor/publisher before doing such changes! Often editors/publishers will not accept such changes and undo them.

With `natbib` (used by default by `acmart`) you need to change `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`. To do so:

- make a copy of `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` in your document folder and name it, e.g., `Non-ACM-Reference-Format.bst`.
- open `Non-ACM-Reference-Format.bst` in a text editor and search for `FUNCTION { proceedings }`.
- replace the whole function by

  ```
  FUNCTION { proceedings }
  {
    output.bibitem
    editor empty.or.unknown
      { organization output
        organization format.key output }  % gnp - changed from author format.key
      { format.editors output.nonnull }
    if$
    % author format.key output             % gnp - removed (should be either
    %                                        editor or organization
    % output.year.check                    % added (newapa); Schweinebacke: removed
    new.block
    format.btitle format.city "title" output.check        % jtb: added city
    new.sentence
    format.bvolume output
    format.number.series output
    new.sentence
    editor empty.or.unknown % schweinebacke: added
    { } % schweinebacke: added
    { % schweinebacke: added
      organization output
    }% schweinebacke: added
    if$ % schweinebacke: added

    % jtb: normal order: publisher, address
    publisher empty.or.unknown
       { }
       { "\bibinfo{publisher}{" publisher * "}" * output }
    if$
    address empty.or.unknown
       { }
       { "\bibinfo{address}{" address * "}" * output }
    if$
    fin.block
    output.issue.doi.coden.isxn.lccn.url.eprint.note
    new.block                        % schweinebacke: added
    output.year.check                % schweinebacke: added
    fin.entry
  }
  ```
- change

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
  ```

  in your document into

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{Non-ACM-Reference-Format}
  ```
- do again run `bibtex` and also `pdflatex`.

The result would be

[image]

Note: In our days often usage of `biblatex` is recommended, because you can do changes of the bibliography with `biblatex` without `bst` hacking. To use `biblatex` with `acmart` you have to pass option `natbib=false`. In this case you could start with standard numeric style and change the formatting of the entries step by step.

Comment: Great, thanks! Regarding biblatex, the documentation for acmart says _You may disable loading of natbib by using the option
natbib=false in \documentclass. However, it is not recommended, as well as the use
of BibTEX styles other than ACM-Reference-Format.bst, and may delay the processing
of the manuscript._ So will stick to bibtex for now :)

Comment: @TomHirschowitz But in this case you also should not change `ACM-Reference-Format` but use the format as it is, because the change could delay the processing of the manuscript and even the publisher/editor could undo the change.

Comment: @TomHirschowitz  Nevertheless, if the answer was useful, [you should vote for it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: You may be right.  I did vote for your answer but my reputation is too low for it to count!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to @Schweinebacke's answer.

It is relatively easy to change bibliographic formatting.  However, when you use "official" styles like ACM, you'd better not do it.  The reason is, publishers like ACM created their own 'house style', and insist on it being followed.  This is the reason their styles are given to the authors.  Changing this subverts the purpose of "official" styles.  You may prefer your way of formatting, but if you do not want problems with the publisher, please use theirs.

A self-respecting publisher just cannot allow two papers in the same journal or book to use different formatting.

I am afraid that the right way to change the formatting is to petition ACM to change their specifications.  Then it would be easy for me to accommodate.  This is not a TeXnical question, but a design question.

Comment: Agreed, but I was more using acmart because I like it!

Comment: Thanks - as the acmart maintainer I am glad people like it!